# How do I fix a transaction error?

Tags: fedora, yum, upgrade

I have Transaction check error between `nodejs-0.10.33-1nodesource.fc20.x86_64` and `nodejs-semver-2.1.0-1.fc20.noarch`. Full error at  [gist:8998690a05100b1f6085](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8998690a05100b1f6085)

When I run yum list nodejs I get:

```
Installed Packages
nodejs.x86_64                0.10.32-1.fc20                           @updates  
Available Packages
nodejs.i686                  0.10.32-1.fc20                           updates   
nodejs.x86_64
```

If I only have one package installed how can I have a conflict? And, what do I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a transaction error from what I can see, it's a file conflict. IMO (maybe someone can correct me) you pretty much have to remove the `npm` package. Either physically or just from the RPM database.

- If you're comfortable with it, you can just do a `rpm -e npm` to uninstall the package and remove the conflicting files from the filesystem. This would cause data loss but if the conflicts exist because `nodejs` is a full replacement for the `npm` package, then there shouldn't be much loss as installing `nodejs` will replace the files lost due to the uninstall.
- If you don't think you can get away with removing the package (it has files the other package doesn't have) you might try your luck with the `--justdb` option to `rpm -e`. Be forwarned that this can cause conflicts that you won't necessarily see immediately (where conflicting versions of files are both installed or fragments of the old package remain on the system, etc). You just have to take an educated guess as to whether all will be alright as long as the files are overwritten.

Example:

```
[root@vml-lvprod04 ~]# ll -h /usr/bin/nc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 22K Feb  9  2010 /usr/bin/nc
[root@vml-lvprod04 ~]# rpm -e --justdb nc
[root@vml-lvprod04 ~]# rpm -ql nc
package nc is not installed
[root@vml-lvprod04 ~]# ll -h /usr/bin/nc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 22K Feb  9  2010 /usr/bin/nc
[root@vml-lvprod04 ~]# yum install -y nc
[ ...snip... ]
Running Transaction
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
  Installing : nc-1.84-22.el6.x86_64            1/1
  Verifying  : nc-1.84-22.el6.x86_64            1/1

Installed:
  nc.x86_64 0:1.84-22.el6

Complete!
```

As you can see I removed the package from the DB without touching the actual file itself. This will prevent `rpm` from seeing any file conflicts. I was then able to install a package with a file in the same location without yum erroring out. `rpm` is designed to anticipate conflicts, so again use at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks Joel. Great information. I made the mistake, at the behest of a tutorial, of installing npm. After researching a bit more on the subject, aided by your answer I found out that as of nodejs 0.6.3 npm is bundled in the nodejs environment. The only thing I did differently than you instructed is, I used yum remove npm because yum was the tool I Used to install in the first place.